# Union and Class

Tags: c++, oop, unions

I have a lot of free time ( there are also the Xmas holidays incoming! ) so, I tried to merge my two passions, video games and c++.
It is not a real video game project, was just some console script using classes.
So, here it comes the problem;

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>

class m4a1 {
    public:
        int Damage = 12;
        int Mag = 30;
};

class ak47 {
    public: 
        int Damage = 14;
        int Mag = 24;
};

union Gun_Union {
    m4a1 M4A1_Union;
    ak47 Ak47_Union;
};

class Player {
    public:
        Gun_Union Gun_Player;
        int Health = 200;
};

template <typename Type> 
void Shot(Type* Player_Obj) {
    Player_Obj->Gun_Player->AK47_Union->Mag--;
    Player_Obj->Health = Player_Obj->Health - Player_Obj->Gun_Player->AK47_Union->Damage;
}   
int main() {

    Player Player_Obj;
    Player_Obj.Gun_Player;
    Shot <Player> (&Player_Obj);
    std::cout << Player_Obj.Health;
}
```

At the line 35 it gives me the error 
Player::Player(void) trying to refer to an eliminate function.
I discovered that changing Gun_Union with any other type in the class Player (line 25) it doesn't give me an error.

I also ask if the command Player_Obj.Gun_Player = Ak47_Union is possible;
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: `Player_Obj.Gun_Player;` not sure what you wanted to do in this line, however it's not the error.

Comment: Since you use `class` with `public` members I think your types aren’t trivial: I think changing them to become `struct`s without access specifiers should address your problem.

Comment: I did a big update.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your *original* question, your `union` has non-trivial members (because of the initializers), but has no constructor. You need to tell the compiler which of the union's members you want to have initially, because the compiler must construct one or the other. That can be done for example by giving the `union` a constructor.

And then you're mixing `.` and `->` operators.

Here's a version that compiles (I don't dare call it "fixed" though):

```
#include <iostream>

class m4a1 {
public:
  int Damage = 12;
  int Mag = 30;
};

class ak47 {
public:
  int Damage = 14;
  int Mag = 24;
};

union Gun_Union {
  m4a1 M4A1_Union;
  ak47 Ak47_Union;
  Gun_Union() : Ak47_Union() {}   // <=== the initial state is ak47
};

class Player {
public:
  union Gun_Union Gun_Player;
  int Health = 200;
};

template <typename Type>
void Shot(Type* Player_Obj) {
  Player_Obj->Gun_Player.Ak47_Union.Mag--;
  Player_Obj->Health = Player_Obj->Health - Player_Obj->Gun_Player.Ak47_Union.Damage;
}
int main() {

  Player Player_Obj;
  Player_Obj.Gun_Player;
  Shot <Player>(&Player_Obj);
  std::cout << Player_Obj.Health;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also ask if the command Player_Obj.Gun_Player = Ak47_Union is possible; Sorry for bad English.

So what you're trying to do here is set the player's current weapon to an ak47. Here's the problem. Your union represents a class, not just a regular type. This is a problem for a few reasons.

A class is useful because it provides a blueprint from which to create similar but ultimately different objects. Since all of your weapon classes have the same structure (damage and magsize), there's no reason to have separate classes for each weapon.

Furthermore, a class here is tricky because in order for you to *use* a class, you must first either instantiate it or declare it's member functions static. The problem here comes from the fact that you're using a union to handle the player weapon. A union won't work because unions by definition *hold* things (one at a time), which is not a thing here because we want a static class.

Now, you *could* instantiate your weapon classes and actually add them to the union, like so:

```
int main()
{
    Player Player_Obj;
    Player_Obj.Gun_Player;

    // Remember to pick better names for classes, not the metasynctactic
    // b.s. I'm using
    m4a1 m4a1_class_instance;
    ak47 ak47_class_instance;

    // Populate the union
    union Gun_Union weapons;
    weapons.Ak47_Union = ak47_class_instance;

    // Finally, set player weapon
    Player_Obj.Gun_player = weapons;

    // <Rest of program...>
```

As I'm sure you can tell, this is clunky and doesn't really make sense. Why are we istantiating those classes? It doesn't really make sense. I think a redesign here would be great, especially because you wouldn't have to deal with the union, which was tripping you up with regards to setting the player's weapon. Here is a pretty basic one.

```
// Using constants for simplicity

// Weapon Ids
const auto M4A1 = 1000;
const auto AK47 = 1001;

const auto FIRST_WEAPON_ID = M4A1;
const auto LAST_WEAPON_ID = AK47;

class Player {
    int weapon_id;
    int health;
    int damage;
    int magazine_capacity;
    int magazine;

public:
    void setWeapon(const int weapon_id) {
        // Validate id first; you should somehow handle error,
        // I'm just exiting the function here
        if ((weapon_id < FIRST_WEAPON_ID) || (weapon_id > LAST_WEAPON_ID)) return;

        switch (weapon_id) {
            case M4A1: {
                damage = 12;
                magazine_capacity = 30;
            } break;

            case AK47: {
                damage = 14;
                magazine_capacity = 24;
            } break;

            default: // Error should have been handled in validation, but
                     // it's best practice to guard your code everywhere
                return;
        }
    }
};
```

This wouldn't be the full class obviously, I only wrote one function just to show you how I would implement a more naive method, but the actually implementation details are up to you, I would really stress the design concepts, specifically the following:

**Accessing Class Members**

You don't want to access class members directly, especially when you're talking about a pointer. The problem of 'who owns the data pointed to by the pointer' is a significant one, and it's why we now have shared and unique pointers. Regardless of which pointer you use though, you should have something like `<return-type> getValue() const`. That way your data is protected by a layer of indirection. Likewise, to set a value you can do something like `void setValue(const <type> value)` and now you can do validation or whatever in that function.

**Unions**

First, I don't recommend using unions. In your particular case, using a union doesn't really make sense because you already have the pointer in the player class *(before you edited your question)*, which means a player can already only hold one. Having a union doesn't add anything at that point. Additionally, using unions isn't recommended, mostly because you lose some type-safety. If you do want something union-like, you might want to check out std::variant in the STL.

**Your Template Function**

Generally speaking, template functions are for generic programming, where they can take in a type T and you don't have to worry about rewriting code unnecessarily. In your case, it shouldn't apply.

You mentioned you were just doing this for practice, so I understand a clean design wasn't your goal, but I think it's never too early to start thinking about design principles.